# Check if row Value is increasing / decreasing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like excel to check if year to year sales is increasing/decreasing.
If it increase year to year then it could indicate "true" or something. 
If for example one of the year is decrease i.e. lower than previous year then its a "false"

For example,

Row 1, has the value with "1", "3", "7", "8" in the column. excel will indicate true.

Row 2, has the value with "1", "3", "2", "5" in the column. excel will indicate false as one of the year is lower than the previous year.

Not sure if there is any formula that can do this.

Your help is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility might be to use `SUMPRODUCT` and `COUNT`.

If your data is in `A1:D2`, try the following in `E1` and drag down as needed. Note that this can be expanded to handle as many columns as needed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:D1>A1:C1))=COUNT(B1:D1)
```

[image]

If you want to consider no change year-over-year as still increasing, change the `>` to `>=`.

Comment: Is it possible to change the formula so that it will take A1:to the last column with data? Many Thanks.

Comment: You could widen the ranges out past where your data is, and add an additional condition that the cells not be blank. For example, `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:AL1>=A1:AK1)*(B1:AL1<>""))=COUNT(B1:AL1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:J1<>0),--(B1:J1<A1:I1))=0
```

([courtesy TMS](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/799955-check-value-increase-continuously.html)), *provided* no blank and no `0` after the start of the series.

Stable year-on-year counts as 'increasing'.

Comment: Thanks it works too. Could I ask what it the difference between =SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:J1<>0),--(B1:J1<A1:I1))=0 and =SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:D1>A1:C1))=COUNT(B1:D1).

Answer (score -3):

You can compare 1 column to another with an if statement. Something like this:

=if(b1>a1, "true","false")

Comment: Drop the if statement

Comment: Thanks. what if I want to do it for the whole rows of values? from a1:g1 if any of the column value is smaller than the previous i.e. if b1>a1, it will show false